# How to acces string with mixed 1 byte and 2 byte symbols?

Tags: python, utf-8, cyrillic

I read questions and answers for a quiz from a file in UTF-8 encoding but the answer can consists 1 byte symbols (English) and 2 byte symbols (Russian) in the same text:

```
"best car тайота"`
```

I need to write answer replaced with `"*"` so it looks like `"**** *** ******"` to help guess what answer is. For determining length I use

```
len(answer.decode('utf-8'))
```

But in the next hint when I want to show *some* symbols like `"b*s* ca* *а*от*"`, I can access the 1 byte symbols via `answer[index]` but I can't read 2 byte symbols this way, and that's why I get `"b*s* ca*"` without 2 byte symbols.

Is there solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode the string to a Unicode value *once*, and do your replacements in that.

A `unicode` string object supports the same operations as byte strings; just be careful when mixing byte strings and Unicode strings as that could trigger an automatic encode or decode (leading to `UnicodeEncode` or `UnicodeDecode` errors). Printing the string should automatically encode the value to match your terminal codec.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)